# Creating a set of identical UIImageView subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I am creating a simple set of UIImageViews which all use the same image and are evenly spaced vertically across the screen. Initially I simply hard-coded the creation of each individual view but I want to make it more compact since they are all the same images anyway.

Here is my current code, which XCode is complaining about (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION). loadingView is a UIView used to group all the images together.

```
let items = [UIImageView?](count:7, repeatedValue: nil)

for item in items {
    item!.image = UIImage(named: "loading_items")
}

// could potentially iterate through this too
self.loadingView.addSubview(items[0]!)
items[0]!.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top)
self.loadingView.addSubview(items[1]!)
items[1]!.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: items[0]!, withOffset: 12)
self.loadingView.addSubview(items[2]!)
items[2]!.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: items[1]!, withOffset: 12)
self.loadingView.addSubview(items[3]!)
items[3]!.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: items[2]!, withOffset: 12)
self.loadingView.addSubview(items[4]!)
items[4]!.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: items[3]!, withOffset: 12)
self.loadingView.addSubview(items[5]!)
items[5]!.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: items[4]!, withOffset: 12)
self.loadingView.addSubview(items[6]!)
items[6]!.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: items[5]!, withOffset: 12)

for item in items {
    item!.autoAlignAxis(.Vertical, toSameAxisOfView: loadingView) // uses AutoLayout
}
```

I want to know what is wrong with this code and if there is a more efficient and 'Swift-y' way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIStackView and add your UIImageView as subview of stack view and add the stackview as subview for superview. This will make your work easy
//ImageView (view1,view2,view3)

```
UIImageview *view1 = [[UIImageview alloc] init];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [view1.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;
    [view1.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:120].active = true;

UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] init];
    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualSpacing;
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
    stackView.spacing = 30;


    [stackView addArrangedSubview:Imageview1];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:Imageview2];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:Imageview3];

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [self.view addSubview:stackView];


    //Layout for Stack View
    [stackView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = true;
    [stackView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor].active = true;
```

Comment: If my stack view of images takes up more space than there is on the screen, does this resize them to fit or simply cut them off (I want them to be cut off)?

Comment: Make it more simple .....add collectionview and customize the UIcollectionviewcell that contains only image view......and add number of rows equals to number of imageviews . As collection view are child of scroll view you dont have to worry about scrolling ........In this case you have to add the stack view in scrollview ......

Comment: Why is that simpler than using UITableView?

Comment: You can customize the collection view to scroll horizontally and vertically both .....in future if you need to scroll horizontally the you have to use collection view ......unless UITableview and UICollectionview are same ......i use collectionview instead of UItableview bcs customization is easy in UIcollectionview.